# fetch api gives GET "url" net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 for some urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I want to fetch more than 100 image from an `array` of URLs. I checked every URL individually all are good. But when I fetch it from my code for **`some URLs`** I got this error

```
GET https://image-url net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
```

Here is my code

```js
var imageUrls = [//contains more than 100 urls];

Promise.all(imageUrls.map(image => {
  fetch(image).then(res => {
    //this console log gives every response correctly
    console.log(res.blob());
  });
})).then(imageBlobs => {
  //do something here
});
```

I also tried this

```js
var imageUrls = [//contains more than 100 urls];

let counter = 0;
imageUrls.forEach(function(image, i){

  let imageBlob = fetch(image).then(res => res.blob());
  
  console.log(imageBlob);
  
  counter ++;
  
  if(counter == imageUrls.length){
    // do something
  }
});
```

Also this

```js
var imageUrls = [//contains more than 100 urls];

Promise.all(imageUrls.map(image => {

  console.log(fetchImage(image));
  
})).then(imageBlobs => {
  //do something here
});

async function fetchImage(url){
  return await fetch(url).then(res => res.blob());
}
```

But in this code I am also getting `TypeError : failed to fetch`.

I think this may be some kind of looping issue because `loop` executes fast but `fetch()` could not handle URLs that fast.

Can someone tell me how I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: What happens when you open `https://image-url` directly in a browser?

Comment: I can see image

Answer (score 1):

I found some flaws in your code:

Code snippet 1:
By using `console.log(res.blob());` you are consuming the response body and you do not pass it to the next ".then()". Also, res.blob() is an async function. So you have to await it or use .then() on it!

Code snippet 2:
Same as in 1 and also this line
`let imageBlob = fetch(image).then(res => res.blob());`
should be this `let imageBlob = await fetch(image).then(res => res.blob());`. Also, by using .forEach() you are fetching all 100 images at the same time! You are executing an asynchronous function in a synchronous loop while not awaiting for it to end.

Code snippet 3:
Same as in 1. `console.log(fetchImage(image));` should be at least `console.log(await fetchImage(image));` or since you are passing it to the next .then it should be `return fetchImage(image);`

EDIT: Could it be that you are getting CORS errors? I just saw a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66023969/i-have-some-doubts-regarding-the-fetch-api-in-case-of-errors/66024122#66024122) that had a similar problem.

Comment: I am not actually doing `console.log()` in my code. This error occurs even if I remove this. And have no idea of `CORS`. I have mentioned the error in my question